# Could someone please check my Tkinter and python code with a textfile?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I have written my code and it works. It involves the use of tkinter and python and it works. However, there is one thing that I am not able to fix.

The one thing that I am not able to fix is in the last part of the code that is labeled with a comment and called "#Please fix part" and what is happening is that I can either press the right or left key to start the timer. However, the "Thanks for playing" message shows up only after pressing the right arrow key.
Additionally, why is the textfile not working?

Thanks for helping me!

Here is a link to the python code. The name of the file is BB.py
https://github.com/a210082/I2P-Summative

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works:
Firstly, I Believe the problem is here:

```
bb.unbind("<Right>")
bb.unbind("Left")
```

Where it should be:

```
bb.unbind("<Right>")
bb.unbind("<Left>")
```

and I only presume that's the problem because I could not find your comment.

With the textfile, the code should end with a close function. like so:

```
Balancetxt = open("scoreBaBo.txt","a+")
Balancetxt.write(str(timestr))
Balancetxt.write("\n")
```

+

```
Balancetxt.close()
```

I hope this helps!